# How do i connect MongoDb models

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mern

I am using MERN stack. I have 3 models created for my database user, subject and comment. Subject and comment both have author properties set to type mongoose.ObjectId but this only saves the id and not the full object. What should i change it to so that all the user information shows?

```
author: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
  },
```

Comment: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

Comment: This still only shows the string for the id rather than the object.

Answer (score 1):

> but this only saves the id and not the full object

that's the intended behaviour when using refrences. saving the refrence id, but allowing to access the full object by that id.

> What should i change it to so that all the user information shows?

By using `populate`, you can expand your result to replace the id by whole object, when you access it.

```
Subject.find({}).populate('author').then(subjects => {
  // now subjects[0].author is the whole object of author.
})
```

[learn more about populate here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)